# Add/Remove Class in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a button cart on opencart.
I have this code:

```
    /* Ajax Cart */
$('#cart > .heading a').live('click', function() {
    $('#cart').addClass('active');

    $('#cart').load('index.php?route=module/cart #cart > *');

    $('#cart').live('mouseleave', function() {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

On desktop work well, when I click on button open cart window, when I leave mouse it dissapear.
But on mobile when I click, it open cart window, but dont dissapear anymore.
So on mobile I would like to dissapear when I click in any place outside that cart.

Something like that (but I know it doesnt work):

```
$('#cart').live('clickoutside', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
});
```

Hope you can understand me. Thank you!

Comment: That's because you have no a mouse in the mobile. In UX perspective, add a close button in mobile

Comment: The `live` method was deprecated some time ago. Use `on` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common problem. You'll find it easily been dealt with on dropdown menus.

I cannot test the code at the moment but I'm pretty sure this will work for you:

```
$(document).on("click", function() {
  if ($(this).closest("#cart").length === 0) {
    $('#cart').removeClass("active");
  }
});
```

Let me explain why this works. On every click on the page, check if the click's target is inside #cart (i.e. check if any of the ancestor matches #cart selector).

If it's not, remove the cart's active class. This will allow clicks inside the cart and not close it.

Here's the documentation for it. [jQuery.closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Comment: I added your code after my code, but doesnt work unfortunately. I should put inside my code, or after ? I mean before my }); or after ?

Comment: Or another idea. I could remove that mouseleave, and open and close cart when I click ? Hoping that it will work on both, desktop and mobile.

Comment: After, and you may need to preventDefault and stopPropagation on the opening click event, so this one doesn't trigger